# Picking A Number Game

Tags: logical-deduction, strategy, optimization

Alice and Bob play a game starting from Alice where Alice and Bob are supposed to write a number to the board, Then the game goes through several rounds between Alice and Bob with the rules below:

- Alice goes first and writes on the board a positive integer less than or equal to our top-limit number $2017$. *After this, neither player can write down either that number or any of its divisors.*
- Then Bob writes another number, after which again *neither player can write down that number or any of its divisors*.
- Alice and Bob continue to take turns to write a new number no multiple of which has been written before.
- Whoever manages to play last is the winner.

And As we all know Alice and Bob, they are smart and play the optimal strategy.

**For example,**

Let say the top limit number was $5$:

$1-2-3-4-5$

> Alice: $4$ (Then $1$,$2$ and $4$ would be eliminated)

$ - -3- -5$

> Bob: $5$

$ - -3- - $

> Alice: $3$

**Alice Wins!**

> Who will win at the end, with best play on both sides, if the top-limit is $2017$?

Comment: You're welcome! I hope I haven't made your puzzle unrecognizable.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan you made it better!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This game

> is a first-player win whatever our "top limit" is.

Here's why:

> Suppose first of all that the first player begins by playing 1. Perhaps this leads to a win for the first player with best play, in which case we've found a winning first move and we're done. Otherwise, the *second* player has a win from that point; let's say they win by playing *n*. OK then: the first player can begin by playing *n*, leading to the exact same position as after 1, *n* but with the roles reversed -- which means that the first player wins.

In summary,

> if opening with 1 is not a win for the first player, then opening with what the second player refutes it with is a win for the first player.

Comment: @Oray [Still works for top limit 7.](https://pastebin.com/HMbWR8VP)

Comment: @ΈρικΚωνσταντόπουλος you are right :)

Comment: Is it necessary that in a game without draws, some player must be able to force a win?

Comment: Yes. Suppose player 1 cannot force a win. Then player 2 can play in such a way as to guarantee that player 1 doesn't win. Since there are no draws (note: I assume infinitely-prolonged play counts as a draw for this purpose) the only way this can happen is for player 2 to win instead.